# SQL SERVER: Check if variable is null and then assign statement for Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case

I am trying to achieve something like the below in WHERE clause in sql.

```
if (@zipCode ==null)
begin
([Portal].[dbo].[Address].Position.Filter(@radiusBuff) = 1)   
end
else if(@zipCode !=null)
begin
([Portal].[dbo].[Address].PostalCode=@zipCode )
end
```

I tried the following:

```
WHERE ((@zipCode IS NOT NULL AND ([Portal].[dbo].[Address].PostalCode=@zipCode)) OR (@zipCode IS NULL AND ([Portal].[dbo].[Address].Position.Filter(@radiusBuff) = 1)))
```

which is wrong. Can anyone help in framing the exact statement. Thanks!

Comment: So, why is it wrong?, what are your expected results?

Comment: is [Portal].[dbo].[Address].Position.Filter supposed to be a function?

Comment: Your where condition seems to be fine...what problem or issue do you have??

Comment: When I am manually passing zipcode as null, it is not returning any result. But when I am replacing the entire statement to ([Portal].[dbo].[Address].Position.Filter(@radiusBuff) = 1)) its working fine. I did not know why it happening like this. When I am breaking up the statements and executing seperatly with the values defined, they work great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isnull() syntax is built in for this kind of thing.

```
declare @Int int = null;

declare @Values table ( id int, def varchar(8) )

insert into @Values values (8, 'I am 8');

-- fails
select *
from @Values
where id = @Int

-- works fine
select *
from @Values
where id = isnull(@Int, 8);
```

For your example keep in mind you can change scope to be yet another where predicate off of a different variable for complex boolean logic.  Only caveat is you need to cast it differently if you need to examine for a different data type.  So if I add another row but wish to specify int of 8 AND also the reference of text similar to 'repeat' I can do that with a reference again back to the 'isnull' of the first variable yet return an entirely different result data type for a different reference to a different field.

```
declare @Int int = null;

declare @Values table ( id int, def varchar(16) )

insert into @Values values (8, 'I am 8'), (8, 'I am 8 repeat');

select *
from @Values
where id = isnull(@Int, 8)
and def like isnull(cast(@Int as varchar), '%repeat%')
```

Answer (score 25):

is null is the syntax I use for such things, when COALESCE is of no help.

Try:

```
if (@zipCode is null)
  begin
    ([Portal].[dbo].[Address].Position.Filter(@radiusBuff) = 1)   
  end
else 
  begin
    ([Portal].[dbo].[Address].PostalCode=@zipCode )
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

`is null` can be used to check whether `null` data is coming from a query as in following example:

```
 declare @Mem varchar(20),@flag int
select @mem=MemberClub from [dbo].[UserMaster] where UserID=@uid
if(@Mem is null)
begin
    set @flag= 0;
end
else
begin
    set @flag=1;
end
return @flag;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a case statement

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN @zipCode IS NULL THEN 1
ELSE @zipCode
END
```

Comment: You don't have a conditional operation in your where clause.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```sql
if ((select VisitCount from PageImage where PID=@pid and PageNumber=5) is NULL)
begin
    update PageImage
    set VisitCount=1
    where PID=@pid and PageNumber=@pageno
end 
else
begin
    update PageImage 
    set VisitCount=VisitCount+1
    where PID=@pid and PageNumber=@pageno
end
```